# Field component not providing 'input.onChange' property

Tags: redux-form

on the Redux form docs (http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/api/Field.md/) for Field, it says there is supposed to be an onChange property (props.input.onChange), but my components dont' get provided with any such property.

```
const customComponent = props => {
    console.log(`input: ${JSON.stringify(props.input)}`);
    return (
        <Jsx ... />
    );
};


//Using it:
<Field name="link_id" component={customComponent} />
```

This prints `input: {"name":"link_id","value":""}`
Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Your component has those properties, they are not printed because  `JSON.stringify` can't just stringify and output any functions (such as `onChange`).
What you see running your code are only the properties of your `Field` (`name` and `value`) which are strings and thus can be stringified and printed.

If you want to explore your `Field` object just use `debugger` in your component or use breakpoints or simply 
`console.log(props.input.onChange);`